# Suffix List of Strings with the number of times they were repeated before in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, dictionary, immutability

If we have a List of strings, create a new List where each repeated element has a suffix of the number of times it was repeated, with order preserved.

Example:
List("a","a","a","b","b","c","C") should become List("a","a.1","a.2","b","b.1","c","C")

I could loop through each element, update a map that counts the number of times each element is seen, then add each to a List, but there must be more "Scala way" of doing this.

Comment: Sets don't have order so the question is already badly redacted. Anyways, take a look to `groupBy` and `zipWithIndex`

Comment: Changed to List

Comment: What should be the output of `List("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b")`?

Comment: What do you mean with more scala way? Do you have some code that is not working? It is working but you think it could be refactored? Have you written some unit test and they are failing?

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this with plain scala using recursive traversal and pattern matching. It's not just scala but a functional way.

```scala
val initList = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "C")

@tailrec
def loop(list: List[String], res: Vector[List[String]] = Vector.empty): List[String] = {
  list match {
    case Nil =>
      res.flatMap(_.reverse.zipWithIndex.map { case (str, idx) => if (idx == 0) str else s"$str.$idx" }).toList
    case xs =>
      val (same, rest) = xs.span(_ == xs.head)
      loop(rest, res :+ same)
  }
}

loop(initList) should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs Seq("a", "a.1", "a.2", "b", "b.1", "c", "C")
```

Or even more elegant with [fs2](https://fs2.io/#/)

```scala
val initList = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "C")

val result =
  fs2.Stream
    .emits(initList)
    .groupAdjacentBy(identity)
    .map { case (_, groups) => groups }
    .map(_.zipWithIndex.map { case (str, idx) => if (idx == 0) str else s"$str.$idx" })
    .flatMap(fs2.Stream.chunk)
    .toList

result should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs Seq("a", "a.1", "a.2", "b", "b.1", "c", "C")
```